# Code formatting in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

I notice that when I copy in Visual Studio that the pasted code has most of it shifted to the left:

```
    class TestClass
    {
        public IEnumerable<MyObject> TestMethod()
        {
            // Code copying from here...
            yield return new MyObject(
              "",
              "",
              ""  
            );
            // ...to here

            // Pasted code looks like this
            yield return new MyObject(
"",
"",
""  
);

            yield return new MyObject(
"",
"",
""  
);

            yield return new MyObject(
"",
"",
""  
);
            // End of pasted code
        }
    }
```

When I hit 'CTRL+K, CTRL+D' or select 'Format Document' from the 'Edit -> Advanced' menu, the code doesn't budge.

I know document formatting works but seems to not work when certain 'special' conditions (e.g. certain indenting) exist.

Is there any way to tell visual studio to just reformat the entire document according to its default rules and ignore 'special' conditions completely?

Answer (score 0):

I see the same behavior with the out-of-the-box Visual Studio, however, when using [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), pasting this code is formatted as expected. You could try a lightweight extension like [Code Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-599079.CodeFormatter) if ReSharper is too heavy / expensive.